# Excel 2016 - Combing Several Colum Titles as Comma Separated Values in a Cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

Please help me someone! I would like to use the column header titles as 'the comma separated value' content in another cell. For a clear example please see the below table structure:

```
[Name]     [Breathing]     [Posture]     [Health]     [Correction(s)]
Roy         Bad             Bad           Bad          Breathing, Posture, Health
Pam         Good            Good          Bad          Health
Joy         Good            Good          Good         None
Sam         Good            Bad           Good         Posture
```

I tried using if conditions but I could only get it to fill in the value for a single column. I need to read the values across multiple columns. These value(s) will then be used as the comma separated content for another cell. If only one correction is needed in terms of the 'Breathing, Posture, Health' for those column headers then the 'Correction(s)' column value for that row will be the column name with the bad value. I read up about visual basic code solutions but that will not work on the excel online browsers version, which I need for team collaboration.

Any feedback at all will be greatly appreciated, because I am sort of new to excel.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Excel 2016 Version.

Comment: :-(  It'd be simple in Office 365.  Will there only ever be three column headers to consider?

Comment: There will be like 6 column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Excel 2016 does not have the `TEXTJOIN` function.

To accomplish what you show, using formulas on the worksheet, you can expand this example for the three columns you show:

```
=MID(IF([@Breathing]="Bad",", " & hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Breathing]],"") &
            IF([@Posture]="Bad",", " & hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Posture]],"") &
            IF([@Health]="Bad",", " &hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Health]],""),3,99)
```

Note that I used a table and structured references, but you can change this to regular references if you prefer.  The formula length should not become an issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but It did not work. I copied and modfied and pasted the following:

=MID(IF([@Rating]="Bad",", " & hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Rating]],"") &
            IF([@Connection]="Bad",", " & hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Connection]],"") &
            IF([@Area]="Bad",", " &hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Area]],""),3,99)

Comment: The error in excel stated: verify that the name starts with a letter or underscore (_) / Doesn't include a space or character that isn't allowed / doesn't conflict with an existing name in the workbook

Comment: I even created a new excel file with only the examples data in your image but it still did not work.

Comment: @spencer That formula syntax is valid only when this calculated column is a part of the same table.  The syntax will be different if you are using that formula outside of `hlthTbl`  (and you will get the error message you show)

Comment: thank you so much. It worked beautifully. Now, how would I modify the code to search for other words besides 'Bad', like 'Very Bad', 'Poor';. I am asking this because the 'Breating, Posture and Correction(s)' column is a dropdown and from that simple dropdown the options: Bad, very bad, Poor, Good can be selected. I did not ask originally because I thought that I could just fill it in myself and figure it out. I am very sorry about that. But I will accept you answer because the fault is mine for not being thorough enough.

Comment: @spencer Glad you got it working.  If you want to test for one of several words, you can change the `logical_test` to include the `OR` function and use an **array constant**.  eg:  `OR([@Breathing]={"Bad","Very Bad","Poor"})`  will return `TRUE` if any **one** of the three words is present.

Comment: I have been trying to to let this work:  OR([@Breathing]={"Bad","Very Bad","Poor"})  but with no luck. Could you please help me out providing an example code?

Comment: @spencer I don't know what more to say.  What does "no luck" mean? You just replace the `logical_text` arguments of the `IF` functions with the `OR` function you show, (obviously a different one for each column header).  What does your formula look like?  I suppose you could try confirming the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter` as an array formula, but I didn't think that was required in Excel 2016.

Comment: I am not too familiar with Excel conditions but I tried several things. This is the most recent: =MID(IF([@Breathing]="Bad",", " OR ([@Breathing]={"Bad","Very Bad","Poor"}) & hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Breathing]],"") &
            IF([@Posture]="Bad",", " OR ([@Posture]={"Bad","Very Bad","Poor"}) & hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Posture]],"") &
            IF([@Health]="Bad",", " OR ([@Health]={"Bad","Very Bad","Poor"}) &hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Health]],""),3,99)

Comment: Instead of replacing the `logical_test` with the `OR` construct, you concatenated it as a string to the `value_if_true` argument.  I suggest you read Excel HELP for the `IF` function (and also look at the intellisense hints that pop up when you enter a formula) so as to understand better the different arguments to the function.  You'll learn a lot more that way, and be better off for future projects.

Comment: I have read several articles but their examples are for simple things that is not as complicated as this. The example code I sent is just one of the many things that I have tried. I am just struggling with the coding construct in Excel because it is very new to me.

Comment: In addition to MS Help, you can also use the insert function wizard to sort out the different arguments. The `IF` function has three arguments.  The first argument is `logical_test`. You have multiple `IF` functions in your formula.  To modify the first one, it would look like `IF(OR([@Breathing]={"Bad","Very Bad","Poor"}),", " & hlthTbl[[#Headers],[Breathing]],"")`