# Use Table Header as Content In a Cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

I am using the column header titles as the comma separated content in another cell. I am using Excel 2016. I have a table named **StudentCourse** and for a better illustration please see the below example layout:

```
[Name]     [Math]     [Geo]     [Bio]     [Fees]     [Fixes]
Ram         Very Bad   Good      Good      Unpaid     Urgent: Math, Fees
Dam         Neutral    Good      Bad       Paid       Urgent: Math, Bio
Rik         Good       Good      Good      Paid       OK: Not Urgent
Nik         Good       Good      Good      Partial    Urgent: Fees
```

The values for the subject columns are from a drop down menu which has the options **Good, Neutral, Bad and Very Bad** and if the values **Neutral, Bad or Very Bad** are selected then the **Fixes** column will be updated with the prefix **Urgent:** and the column header name (**Math, Geo or Fees**) depending on what needs to be fixed. If, no fixes are needed then the **Fixes** column's value will be **Ok: Not Urgent**.

The Fees column also follows the same concept. Meaning that if the **Partial (means partial payment) or unpaid** dropdown options are selected for the Fees Column value, then the Fees will be added to the Fixes column. So in short the **Fixes** column is for easily sorting through what needs to be given special by having the values be automatically selected based on what was chosen for the other columns.

I should also mention that I am new to Excel.

Comment: This seems like homework. What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried using the JOIN and MID with the with and/or operators. I also got a selecting multiple dropdown options to work but was too repetitive. I actually need something that will be automatic. It is not homework though. It is for a project that I am working on.

Comment: The explanation says: *"if No or Partial is selected from the Fees column dropdown options then likewise that will be added to the fixes column."* However the Table shows a different behavior. Please clarify.

Comment: @EEM sorry about that. I have updated the original question and that portion now reads: if the **Partial or No** dropdown options are selected for  the Fees Column value, then the Fees will be added to the Fixes column. So in short the **Fixes** column is for easily sorting through what needs to be given special by having the values be automatically selected based on what was chosen for the other columns.

Comment: Would you also adjust the Fixes column in the table to reflect the update.

Comment: Guys I have been fiddling around and this question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68145823/excel-2016-combing-several-colum-titles-as-comma-separated-values-in-a-cell comes close to what I am attempting. The only thing is that when I tested it out I do not know how to modify the code to add the prefixes: Urgent: and OK: to the fixes column. Could you or someone else please help me out in doing it. Also, I am learning about excel and would love to find any other solutions that might do the same thing in an easier manner. Thank you all so much everyone!

Comment: What excel version do you have?

Comment: @EEM I just edited the question. It should be a lot easier to understand now. For the Fees it was a bit confusing with the Yes, No and Partial options. So I adjusted it to say Paid, Unpaid or Partial. I am using Excel 2016. Thank you! :)

Comment: Would any cell be [Blank] or they must always have one of the `Drop Down` values?

Comment: @EEM there will not be any blank values. The values will always be chosen from the dropdown options. You are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the table is located at `[A1:E9]` and there are no [BLANK] cells as confirmed by OP. Enter this formula in `[F2]` and copy it to `[F3:F9]`.

**Excel 2016**

```
= IF( SUMPRODUCT( ($B2:$E2<>{"Good","Good","Good","Paid"})*1 )=0, "Ok: Not Urgent",
 "Urgent: " & SUBSTITUTE(
 IF( $B2<>"Good", ", " & $B$1, "" )
 & IF( $C2<>"Good", ", " & $C$1, "" )
 & IF( $D2<>"Good", ", " & $D$1, "" )
 & IF( $E2<>"Paid", ", " & $E$1, "" ), ", ", "", 1 ) )
```

[image]

**Excel 2019** *(Formula Array)*

```
= IF( SUMPRODUCT( ($B2:$E2<>{"Good","Good","Good","Paid"})*1 )=0, "Ok: Not Urgent",
 "Urgent: " &
 TEXTJOIN( ", ", TRUE, IF( ($B2:$E2<>{"Good","Good","Good","Paid"}), $B$1:$E$1, TEXT(,) ) ) )
```

*The `FormulaArray` is entered holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>  simultaneously, the formula would be wrapped within `{` and `}` if entered correctly.*

[image]

Comment: You are a Genius! This is so straight forward and helpful!!! I have been watching so many videos on Excel and you managed to do a better job in words and images. It is very clear and straight forward. Thank you so much. One thing though, I know you asked me this earlier but I did not understood that if the rows are blank it would automatically fill in the **Fixes** column with false alerts for the **subjects and Fees**. Is there a workaround, so that whenever I enter a new row I won't get false fix messages in the **Fixes** column. I'll select your answer but can you please help me with this?

Comment: I am playing around with the code and I realized that if I insert a column inbetween it breaks the code. How do I code it to say that only these columns **Math, Geo, Bio and Fees** should be used to decide what goes into the **FIxes** Column? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On my actual sheet I have other values like **Excellent, Satisfactory** that like **Good** would not trigger an alert in the **Fixes Column**. I am so sorry about this. I thought that once I had the code I could just modify it fill in the rest but Excel is a lot different from PHP and Javascript. But I am still trying to learn it and would greatly appreciate any help at all! Thank you again.

Comment: I just want you to know that I am actually reading up and trying things out. So far this is my attempt to select across different ranges. It seems logical but it is not working: = IF( SUMPRODUCT( ($B2:$B2,$D2:$D2<>{"Good","Good"})*1 )=0, "Ok: Not Urgent",
 `"Urgent: " & SUBSTITUTE(
 IF( $B2:$B2<>"Good", ", " & $B$1, "" )
 & IF( $D2:$D2<>"Good", ", " & $D$1, "" ), ", ", "", 1 ) )`

Answer (score 0):

If you list the acceptable data in column H:I (as example below). You could use:
`=IF(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(INDEX($I$1:$I$4,MATCH($B$1:$E$1,$H$1:$H$4,0))=B2:E2,"",$B$1:$E$1))="","OK: No urgent","Urgent: "&TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(INDEX($I$1:$I$4,MATCH($B$1:$E$1,$H$1:$H$4,0))=B2:E2,"",$B$1:$E$1)))`
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but this one does not work well my already fleshed out table structure. But it is a great learning experience for me and I will save this code.

Comment: I found this question on Stackoverflow: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68145823/excel-2016-combing-several-colum-titles-as-comma-separated-values-in-a-cell) that comes close to what I am attempting. The only thing is that when I tested it out I do not know how to modify the code to add the prefixes: Urgent:... and OK: Not Urgent to the fixes column. Could you please help me to modify it. Also, I am learning about Excel and would welcome any other solutions that does with an easier approach if possible. Thank you!

Comment: I am testing out your code some more because I want to learn as much as possible, however the fixes column instead gets filled with: #NAME? I copied your exact table structure so I am not sure what is wrong. I am using Excel 2016

Comment: Your Excel probably doesn't support TEXTJOIN.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for all of your assistance though. I still enjoyed playing with your code :)